# trying to put name of country from json file into path title

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm using d3 to get a globe onto a web page. I'm able to append a title for each path on the globe (a path = a country polygon). But I'm having trouble making the title be the *name* of the country.

```
var svg = d3.select("#canvas"),
    globe = svg.selectAll(".country"),
    sens = .25, //sensitivity
    circle, 
    zoomed = false;

width = window.innerWidth;                                                          
height = window.innerHeight;

svg
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()                                                          
    .scale(300)
    .translate([width / 2, height /2 ])
    .rotate([0,0])
    .clipAngle(90) 
    .precision(.1);


var path = d3.geo.path()                                                                        
    .projection(projection);


d3.json("world.json", function(error, world) {

    circle = svg.append("circle")                                                               
        .attr('cx', width / 2)
        .attr('cy', height / 2)
        .attr('r', projection.scale())
        .attr("stroke", "#aaaaaa")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("fill", "white");


    countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;                      

    globe = globe.data(countries)
        .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "country")
            .attr("id", function(d){return d.properties.id})
            .on("dblclick", zoomIn)
            .on("click", panTo)
            .append('title').text('This is a line.');
```

So I can put in a string for the title, but how do I put in the country name?

`.append('title').text(function(d){return d.properties.id});` throws the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of
>   null"

Comment: Hmmm, that looks like it should work. What is the exact code you're running that gives you that error?

Comment: When I put in that line, .append('title').text(function(d){return d.properties.id});, I get that error.

Comment: Where do you put in that line? Are you replacing the current `.append("title").text("This is a line.");` with that?

Comment: Yes, I'm replacing the current .append("title"), etc., with that. I put it as the last line.

Comment: Where exactly does it say the error is coming from? The change you're making shouldn't trigger an error like this.

Comment: It doesn't say. When I put the line in, I get the error. When I take it out, no error.

Comment: Does it tell you the line that the code is in that triggered the error?

Comment: @Lars: It doesn't tell me. I think the problem is that my json file of countries doesn't match my database of country names.